# Swift SceneKit nor rounded sphere

Tags: swift, scenekit

I add a sphere node, but when i rotate the node (from touching) the edges of the sphere are not smooth. Is there a way to fix this?

When rotating on X all is good, but in Y sphere is not smooth :(

[image]

```
sceneView.scene = scene

cameraOrbit = SCNNode()
cameraNode = SCNNode()
camera = SCNCamera()

// camera stuff
camera.usesOrthographicProjection = true
camera.orthographicScale = 5
camera.zNear = 1
camera.zFar = 100

cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 70)
cameraNode.camera = camera
cameraOrbit = SCNNode()
cameraOrbit.addChildNode(cameraNode)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 2)
sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
let earthNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
earthNode.name = "sphere"
earthNode.geometry?.materials = [blueMaterial]
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(earthNode)
earthNode.rotation = SCNVector4(0, 1, 0, 0)

let lightNode = SCNNode()
let light = SCNLight()
light.type = .ambient
light.intensity = 200
lightNode.light = light
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
sceneView.cameraControlConfiguration.allowsTranslation = true
sceneView.cameraControlConfiguration.rotationSensitivity = 0.4
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnsphere talks about segmentCount: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnsphere/1523912-segmentcount

Comment: the `geodesic` property can also lead to better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also subdivide your Geometry:

```
node.geometry.subdivisionlevel = 2 // Don't make that more than 3!
```

Note: This will consume more memory, becaue the geometry contains now more vertices (mesh data)